# Выборка данных

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

Имеется следующий набор данных:

```
var Data =  new[] 
{
    new Data{Id = 1, ParentId = 0, Value = "value1"},
    new Data{Id = 2, ParentId = 1, Value = "value1"},
    new Data{Id = 3, ParentId = 1, Value = "value3"},
    new Data{Id = 4, ParentId = 3, Value = "value4"}
};
```

и метод, который необходимо реализовать таким образом, чтобы по заданному Id я мог получить список всех его ParentId и желательно Value

Раз плюнуть:

```
Dictionary<int, string> dict = new Dictionary<int, string>();

public void AllParents(IEnumerable<Data> Data, int id)
{
    var parent = Data.First(x=>x.Id==id);
    dict.Add(parent.Id, parent.Value);
    if(parent.ParentId == 0)
        return;
    AllParents(Data, parent.ParentId);
}

AllParents(Data, 4);    AllParents(Data, 2);
+---------+---------+  +----------+---------+
|Key      |Value    |  | Key      | Value   |
|---------|---------|  |----------|---------|
|4        |value4   |  | 2        | value2  |
|3        |value3   |  | 1        | value1  |
|1        |value1   |  |          |         |
|         |         |  |          |         |
|         |         |  |          |         |
+---------+---------+  +----------+---------+
```

Но как сделать тоже самое, если данные находятся в таблице в БД? Разделить одну таблицу на две или любым другим способом изменить структуру данных - это единственный выход?

Comment: Можно использовать LinqToSql или EntityFramework там тоже есть поддержка linq. Параметер Data вы будете получать в таком же виде, только из базы. Функция AllParents останется без изменений.

Comment: это всё ясно, но не буду же я рекурсивно обращатся к базе, или вы советуете все данные вытащить из базы, преобразовать в объекты и только потом работать с ними? не вариант

Comment: есть вариант с минимальными изменениями структры БД - созданием хранимой процедуры, которая в пакетном режиме (без рекурсии) формирует временную таблицу в формате key/value

Comment: NHibernate + Fluent NHibernate - еще одна альтернатива EF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть вариант на примере Entity Framework:

```
private void AllParents(int id, int maxLevel) {
        using (TestDbEntities context = new TestDbEntities()) {
            var query = context.Data
                .Where(d => d.Id == id);
            for (int i = 2; i <= maxLevel; i++) {
                query = query.Union(
                    context.Data
                        .Join(query.Select(d => d.ParentId), 
                            d => d.Id, pId => pId, (d, pId) => d));
            }
            dict = query.ToDictionary(d => d.Id, d => d.Value);
        }
    }
```

Суть в том, что генерируется единый запрос на основании глубины поиска. Для ваших примеров с id = 4 и id = 2 и глубиной поиска maxLevel = 3 результаты аналогичны. Плюс решения в том, что все данные получаются за один запрос. Минус в том, что этот запрос не хилый, и есть жесткое ограничение по глубине поиска.

Comment: Даааа, запрос и правда не хилый получается, а увеличение глубины поиска усложняет его в геометрической прогрессии, при 10 запрос выполнялся 8 секунд, а его вид наводил страх и ужас!

Но всё равно огромное спасибо, хотя я думаю прийдётся всё таки изменить структуру таблицы=)